# Finding inconsistencies in a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am a rookie in *Mathematica* and apologize in advance.

Here is my question:  Are there any tools, built in the program, of detecting inconsistency in a nonlinear system of equations?  Whilst finding an error in `{x + y = 2, x y = 1, x = 2}` is a simple task, expanding of the size of a system may result in more complex problem.

Comment: `Solve` returns empty curled brackets `{ }` if there are no solution, if that is what you mean.

Comment: As mattiav27 states:  `Solve[{x + y == 2, x y == 1, x == 2}, {x, y, z}]` (note the syntax) returns `{ }`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Solve` sometimes returns empty-handed, even if the equations are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
sys = {x + y == 2, x y == 1, x == 2, x == 1}

(* all partial subsystems *)
subs = Subsets[sys, {1, Length@sys}];

(* The symbols involved *)
vars = Union@Cases[sys, _Symbol, Infinity];

(* Find All inconsistent subsystems*)
Extract[subs, Position[Quiet@Solve[#, vars] & /@ subs, {}]] // Column

(* {
   {x == 2, x == 1},
   {x + y == 2, x y == 1, x == 2}, 
   {x + y == 2,  x == 2, x == 1}, 
   {x y == 1, x == 2, x == 1}, 
   {x + y == 2, x y == 1,  x == 2, x == 1}}
 *)
```

---

And these are the "irreducible cases"

```
e = SortBy[Extract[subs, Position[Quiet@Solve[#, vars] & /@ subs, {}]], Length];
ss = Subsets[#, {1, Length@#}] & /@ e;
Pick[e, Not /@ 
  Join[{False}, 
   Or @@@ Apply[Or, Outer[SameQ, e[[1 ;; # - 1]], ss[[#]], 1] & /@ 
                                                     Range[2, Length@e], {2}]]]

(*{{x == 2, x == 1},
   {x + y == 2, x y == 1, x == 2}}*)
```